# Why does (GNU?) parallel fail silently, and how do I fix it?

Tags: gnu-parallel, moreutils-parallel

In a larger script to post-process some simulation data I had the following line:

```
parallel bnzip2 -- *.bz2
```

Which, if I understand `parallel` correctly (and I may not), should run n-core threads of the program over all files with the listed extension. You may notice that I misspelled the command `bunzip2`. I would expect a warning or error message here, but it fails silently. Is this intended? How do I not get bit by this in the future?

**Update:**

It is possible that I have a different `parallel` installed than I think I do:

```
> parallel --version`


parallel: invalid option -- '-'
parallel [OPTIONS] command -- arguments
    for each argument, run command with argument, in parallel
parallel [OPTIONS] -- commands
    run specified commands in parallel
```

A man page of `parallel` on my system gives:

```
 parallel(1)                                                        parallel(1)
NAME
       parallel - run programs in parallel
....
AUTHOR
   Tollef Fog Heen
```

Which seems this is *not* the GNU version.

Comment: Prints an error on my system.  What does `parallel --version` say?  ```$ parallel bnzip2 -- *
sh: bnzip2: command not found```

Comment: GNU parallel is "Copyright (C) 2010,2011,2012 Ole Tange, http://ole.tange.dk and Free Software Foundation, Inc." (Same author since inception.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have been hit by the confusion with Tollef's parallel from moreutils. See https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/history.html

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: It all makes sense now! For the record, on Ubuntu 12 right now `apt-get install parallel` pulls Tollef's parallel not your GNU version. Thanks for filling me in.

Comment: For Ubuntu 12, see [Where do I get a package for GNU Parallel?](http://askubuntu.com/q/12764/182660)

Answer (score 12):

(I would make this a comment, but I lack the privileges.)

You can also probably just use `parallel --gnu`. You said that Ubuntu 12(.04?) uses Tollef's version, but it's actually the gnu implementation, it just defaults to Tollef's syntax by default for some reason.

I added `alias parallel='parallel --gnu'` to my login script so I don't have to fuss with it anymore.

Comment: You can also add `--gnu` to $HOME/.parallel/config.

Comment: Note: The answer here is addressing a comment from @Hooked.

Comment: See here for another approach plus a bit more detail regarding versions: http://askubuntu.com/a/298598/11522.

Comment: Fedora also frustratingly [puts --tollef in /etc/parallel/config](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=920119). As if that is not obnoxious enough, GNU parallel itself [reports that --tollef will be removed on 20140222](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#options).