# Running up to X commands in parallel

Tags: scripting, gpg, parallelism

I'm running something like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -note -iname "*.gpg" | sort | while read file ; do
    echo "Encrypting $file..."
    gpg --trust-model always --recipient "me@myself.com" --output "$file.gpg" \
        --encrypt "$file" && rm "$file" 
done
```

This runs great, but it seems that GPG is not optimized to use multiple cores for an encryption operation. The files I'm encrypting are about 2GB in size and I have quite a bit of them. I'd like to be able to run X jobs in parallel to encrypt the files and then remove them. How can I do this, setting a limit to, say, 8 jobs at a time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install the [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) tool you can make pretty easy work of what you're trying to accomplish:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -note -iname "*.gpg" | sort | \
      parallel --gnu -j 8 --workdir $PWD '                 \
         echo "Encrypting {}...";                          \
         gpg --trust-model always                          \
           --recipient "me@myself.com" --output "{}.gpg"   \
           --encrypt "{}" && rm "{}"                       \
      '
```

#### details

The above is taking the output of `find` and running it through to `parallel`, and running 8 at a time. Everywhere there's an occurrence of `{}` the filenames that are being passed through from `find` will replace the `{}` in those spots.

#### References

- [Running shell script in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547787/running-shell-script-in-parallel)

Comment: What's with the hanging apostrophe at the end? Is it missing a starting apostrophe?

Comment: @TKKocheran - did that work for you?

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/BWuqBJDF) is what I'm running, and [this](http://pastebin.com/QTWxsxDU) is the output I'm seeing. Not working yet :-|

Comment: What if you move the `sudo` outside of the `find`? Make it a `sudo -i find ..`. I don't think you can pipe to `sudo` in that manner. You could do this: `echo "cmd1" | sudo bash`.

Comment: Looks like I got pwnt with [this problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35953/5614).

Comment: @TKKocheran - Ha. happens to the best of us 8-). I shoot so that it's only once a day ... it's never been once a day 8-). What's your distro? I had to download and re-compile `parallel`  for my Fedora system.

Comment: Ok, so now I'm getting `gpg: can't open \`': No such file or directory`. What the heck? It seems that it's not replacing the `{}`.

Comment: Ah, had to remove `--semaphore`.

Comment: I used this command as a model and it shows 2 lines for each file: `find . | parallel -j 8 --workdir $PWD 'echo {}; echo {}'`.

Comment: This is one heck of a way to load test. Let's cook some cores!

Comment: @TKKocheran - I'd never tried this command till today, thanks for the question, now I know how to do this too!

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at  [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#options) and its `--semaphore` option. From the documentation:

> --semaphore
>
> Work as a counting semaphore. --semaphore will cause GNU parallel to start command in the background. When the number of simultaneous jobs is reached, GNU parallel will wait for one of these to complete before starting another command.

You use `--jobs 8` to limit the number of jobs to 8. You can pipe the output of sort into `parallel` like you would do with `xargs`.
[`sem`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__working_as_mutex_and_counting_semaphore) is an alias for `parallel --semaphore`

Answer (score 0):

I have written an easy-to-use Perl script that allows to control the maximum number commands that are run at the same time: https://github.com/matmu/parallelize_cmds

Might be of interest for you.